# Confusion on Unicode and Multibyte Articles

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, internationalization

By referring [Joel's Article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

> Some people are under the
>   misconception that Unicode is simply a
>   16-bit code where each character takes
>   16 bits and therefore there are 65,536
>   possible characters. This is not,
>   actually, correct.

After reading the whole article, my point is that, if someone told you, his text is in unicode, you will have no idea how much memory space taken up by every of his character. He have to tell you, "My unicode text is encoded in UTF-8", then only you will have idea how much memory space is taken up by every of his character.

**Unicode = not necessary 2 byte for each character**

---

However, when comes to [Code Project's Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/unicode.aspx) and [Microsoft's Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwe8bzh0%28VS.71%29.aspx), this confused me :

Microsoft :

> Unicode is a 16-bit character
>   encoding, providing enough encodings
>   for all languages. All ASCII
>   characters are included in Unicode as
>   "widened" characters.

---

Code Project :

> The Unicode character set is a "wide
>   character" (2 bytes per character) set
>   that contains every character
>   available in every language, including
>   all technical symbols and special
>   publishing characters. Multibyte
>   character set (MBCS) uses either 1 or
>   2 bytes per character

**Unicode = 2 byte for each character ?**

Is 65536 possible characters able to represent all language in this world?

Why the concept seems different among web developer community and desktop developer community?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once upon a time,

- Unicode had only as many characters as fit in 16 bits, and
- UTF-8 did not exist or was not the de facto encoding to use.

These factors led to UTF-16 (or rather, what is now called UCS-2) to be considered synonymous with “Unicode”, because it was after all *the* encoding which supported all of Unicode.

Practically, you will see “Unicode” being used where “UTF-16” or “UCS-2” is meant. This is a historical confusion and should be ignored and not propagated. Unicode is a *set of characters*; UTF-8, UTF-16, and UCS-2 are different *encodings*.

(The difference between UTF-16 and UCS-2 is that UCS-2 is a true 16-bits-per-“character” encoding, and therefore encodes only the “BMP” (Basic Multilingual Plane) portion of Unicode, whereas UTF-16 uses “surrogate pairs” (for a total of 32 bits) to encode above-BMP characters.)

Comment: OK. So, in the above content, unicode means "unicode encoded in UTF-16", and it it not necessary 16 bit per character, and it can more than that. am I right?

Comment: It is true that UTF-16 is not a fixed-width encoding, due to its use of surrogate pairs.
 — 
You will have to determine from other sources or experiment whether the data they call “Unicode” is actually UTF-16 (can have surrogates and represent all of Unicode) or UCS-2 (cannot have surrogates; can only represent the BMP portion of Unicode).
 — 
I have no information on the term “MBCS”.

Comment: Only correctly I would suggest is Unicode is a set of code points. UCS-2 or UTF-16 is the encoding of those code points. The code points are then read and are represented on your screen as a character. Though one character in Simplied Chinese may be made up of many code points.

Comment: Utf-16 superceded UCS-2 (not the same thing).

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Kevin's answer:

The description is Microsoft's Help is quite out of date, describing the state of the world in the NT 3.5/4.0 timeline.

You'll also occasionally see UTF-32 and UCS-4 mentioned as well, most often in the *nix world. UTF-32 is a 32-bit encoding of [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/), a subset of UCS-4. The [Unicode Standard Annex #19](http://unicode.org/reports/tr19/tr19-8.html) describes the differences between them.

The best reference I've found describing the various encoding models is the [Unicode Technical Report #17 Unicode Character Encoding Model](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr17/), especially the tables in section 4.

Answer (score 0):

> Is 65536 possible characters able to represent all language in this world?

No.

> Why the concept seems different among web developer community and desktop developer community?

Because Windows documentation is wrong. It took me a while to figure this out. MSDN says in at least two places that Unicode is a 16-bit encoding:

- http://www.microsoft.com/typography/unicode/cscp.htm
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwe8bzh0.aspx

One reason for the confusion is that at one point Unicode was a 16-bit encoding. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding):

> “Originally, both Unicode and ISO 10646 standards were meant to be fixed-width, with Unicode being 16 bit”

The other problem is that today in Windows APIs strings containing utf-16 encoded string data is usually represented using an array of wide characters, each one being 16-bits long. Despite that that Windows APIs support surrogate pairs of two 16-bit character types, to represent one Unicode code point.

Check out [this blog post](http://area.autodesk.com/blogs/chris/writing_unicode_enabled_windows_applications) for more detailed information on the source of the confusion.